# Override content type when uploading files to GCS with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a large number of files that I need to upload to Google Cloud Storage and add content type to them. All file names don't have an extension, but  content type is the same for all of them.

I tried to use this command `gsutil -m cp -r . gs://bucket_name/`, but it uploads files with `application/octet-stream` content type.

Is there a way to override default content type that GCS sets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata), it gives an example of how to do this:

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
       -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600" cp -r images \
       gs://bucket/images
```